# How to block out an area of the screen on Android?

Tags: android

I'd like to build an app that reserves an area of the screen for a toolbar, as shown here:

[image]

Note that this is **not** simply an overlay - I want my toolbar to dock itself below the active app, forcing the active app to take up less space. I do not want to draw on top of the active app - I want to make space for the toolbar.

The location isn't all that important - if there is some way to dock a toolbar above or below the navigation buttons, or at the top of the screen, all of those solutions are fine. As long as we're not making the user drag it around to get it out of the way, as when YouTube, Maps, or the Phone app, opens up in a floating window - that's not what I want.

Is this at all possible?

(I know this might be a bit controversial, but I promise I have a very relevant and unique use-case - something users will actually want to have on screen at all times for certain apps. I understand this may have implications for battery usage as well. I understand all the implications, but this exact behavior essential for this use-case. Please don't reply with "you shouldn't do that".)

Comment: "Is this at all possible?" -- with a custom Android OS build, yes. Without it, no.

Comment: With this approach you could have the toolbar taking the entire screen, preventing the user to do anything on the device. For that reason I don't think it's possible to do that.

Comment: we obviously wouldn't want a feature that lets you block out the entire screen... I've written a [feature request](https://gist.github.com/mindplay-dk/c718890295538a357c6192cd9c745121), although I'm not sure it was successfully posted - immediately after submitting the form, I just got a message saying I'm not permitted to view the issue I just created. ‍♂️